# matlab for loop function multiple output in matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, output, store

I am looking to create two separate matrices with a for loop over a function that creates two outputs. 
It looks somewhat like this:

```
% prepare output matrixes
output1=zeros(size(input2),1) % corresponds to a vector of length n of the nodes (bank capital
levels in this case)


output2=zeros(size(input2)) % corresponds to an adj matrix of size n

input2=[100,200,300 ... ] % corresponds to a vector of length n with capital levels.     
input1=1:length(input2); % correspounds to vector of [1:n] of individual banks to trigger each   
    bank's default in the model, so [1,2,3,4,5]

% input3 is an nxn adjacency matrix of directed exposures (with 0 along the
% main diagonal)
input3=[0,2190,7708,39034,32088,19584,18694,9923,513,14221; ... ]; %continues much longer ]
input4=0.8 % Loss Given Default (LGD
input5=0.4 % loss % of funding fraction from interbank lending
input6=0.4 % loss % from asset fire sales   

for j=1:input1
   [output1 output2] = function(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5,input6)
   output_matrix(j)=[output1(j) output2(j)]
end
```

Above is my failed attempt. Here is a manually created smaller version of the entire thing.

```
input3 = ...
 [70000, 15000, 24000, 52453; 
  23420, 24252, 10000, 35354; 
  98763, 45666, 96555, 05000; 
  09800, 54444, 04336, 67520]; % interbank loans in the function

input1 = 3; % default_bank

input2=[100000;200000;300000;400000]; % capital levels in the function
input4 = 1; 
input5 = .35; 
input6 = 1; 
% function calls on above inputs
[capital_losses defaulted_banks] = interbank_model( ...
input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6)

% this is the standard output for one iteration with default_bank=3, but I need this for 300+,   so a loop would be helpful... 

capital_losses3 =
1.0e+05 *
     0.5857
     0.2598
     3.0000
     0.0609


defaulted_banks3 =
     0 
     0
     1
     0
```

I would like to get the output for every defaulted bank, i.e.
default_bank=1:4 to be displayed by the for loop as follows:

```
capital_losses_all =

   1.0e+05 *

    1.0000    0.2320    0.5857    0.5857
    0.2867    2.0000    0.2598    0.2598
    1.0716    0.4917    3.0000    3.0000
    0.2816    0.6682    0.0609    0.0609


 defaulted_banks_all =

     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1
```

Every way I found to loop through the different banks that default, that is, through input 1:n, the old vector is overwritten n times by the previous one. I would like to generate a matrix of output1 where the iterations are concatenated for evaluation of each j and the same for output 2 for each value of j as shown in the 4x4 example above... 
I assume there is a simple answer and would be very thankful for any pointers. Thanks, 
Christoph

Comment: I don't see how this would even run. You use `input2` before you define it. Assuming that you're simply hiding the declaration of `input2`, that would make your `for` loop something like `for j = 1:[1 2 3]` which is only going to execute once. As for `output_matrix`, you say you want it to be 3-dimensional but you only use one index. Similarly, `output2` is a 2-dimensional matrix and yet you use only one index. Small examples of the output matrices and the results you want would be very helpful.

Comment: i edited the description, hope this makes it clearer. Thanks

Comment: Okay, so `output1` is a `1x13` row vector (though preallocated as `13x1`) and `output2` is a `13x1` column vector (though preallocated as a `13x13` matrix). This should make `output_matrix` a `13x2` matrix. Is this what you want? Also, I still don't know how you're using `input2` before you declare it.

Comment: thank you @beaker, that is true. I have misallocated the matrices, will correct that and the inputs are all previously specified. they are just very long so i omitted them here. The output of output one should in my view be a 13x13 vector with every itertion of the 1x13 vectors beneach eachother. the same goes for the output2, however, next to one another... I tried it a bit more but didn't succeed. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: Then just make a small example (say, 3x3 instead of 13x13) and clearly show the output you expect.

Comment: @beaker I created a small exemplary output by hand now to show how it should work. How do i programme it in a way that it does so automatically? Thanks a lot

Comment: I see that you've posted another identical question, so I've deleted my answer. I wish you luck.

Comment: Thank you @beaker , for your help. I found that this question became incomprehensible with my edits and didn't know how to make it clearer otherwise.